# Deform 3D cube by drag/drop a vertex using Augmented Reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I have just started to develop in Unity and I wish to develop a simple Augmented Reality application. The objective of the application is to display a 3D Cube on top of an image, that is being detected through my webcam using Vuforia. Next I will use Leap Motion to allow a hand gesture to select one of the blue spheres and drag it to another location making the cube deform at that vertice.

The open 3D cube is an imported 3D model. The blue spheres I added in Unity and added the following script to the cube to make the spheres be attached one of the vertices.

```
void Start()
{
    points = new ArrayList();
    points.Add(point1);
    points.Add(point2);
    points.Add(point3);
    points.Add(point4);
    points.Add(point5);
    points.Add(point6);
    points.Add(point7);
    points.Add(point8);

    foreach (GameObject point in points)
    {
        point.transform.parent = myObject.transform;
    }

    if (transform.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider>())
    {
        transform.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider> ().convex = true;
    }
}

void Update () 
{
    Vector3[] Verticles = new Vector3[] 
    {
        //6 Sides
        //Back Side
        point1.transform.position,point2.transform.position,point3.transform.position,point4.transform.position,
        //Right Side
        point2.transform.position,point6.transform.position,point4.transform.position,point8.transform.position,
        //Front Side
        point5.transform.position,point6.transform.position,point7.transform.position,point8.transform.position,
        //Left Side
        point5.transform.position,point1.transform.position,point7.transform.position,point3.transform.position,
        //Up Side
        point3.transform.position,point4.transform.position,point7.transform.position,point8.transform.position,
        //Down Side
        point1.transform.position,point2.transform.position,point5.transform.position,point6.transform.position,
    };


    int[] Triangles = new int[] 
    {
        2,1,0,
        1,2,3,

        4,7,5,
        7,4,6,

        9,10,8,
        10,9,11,

        12,15,13,
        15,12,14,

        16,19,17,
        19,16,18,

        21,22,20,
        22,21,23, 
    };

    Vector2[] UV = new Vector2[] 
    {

        new Vector2(0,0),
        new Vector2(1,0),
        new Vector2(0,1),
        new Vector2(1,1),

        new Vector2(0,0),
        new Vector2(1,0),
        new Vector2(0,1),
        new Vector2(1,1),

        new Vector2(0,0),
        new Vector2(1,0),
        new Vector2(0,1),
        new Vector2(1,1),

        new Vector2(0,0),
        new Vector2(1,0),
        new Vector2(0,1),
        new Vector2(1,1),

        new Vector2(0,0),
        new Vector2(1,0),
        new Vector2(0,1),
        new Vector2(1,1),

        new Vector2(0,0),
        new Vector2(1,0),
        new Vector2(0,1),
        new Vector2(1,1),
    };

    Vector3[] Normals = new Vector3[]
    {
        Vector3.back,
        Vector3.back,
        Vector3.back,
        Vector3.back,

        Vector3.right,
        Vector3.right,
        Vector3.right,
        Vector3.right,

        Vector3.forward,
        Vector3.forward,
        Vector3.forward,
        Vector3.forward,

        Vector3.left,
        Vector3.left,
        Vector3.left,
        Vector3.left,

        Vector3.up,
        Vector3.up,
        Vector3.up,
        Vector3.up,

        Vector3.down,
        Vector3.down,
        Vector3.down,
        Vector3.down,
    };

    transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices = Verticles;
    transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.triangles = Triangles;
}
```

However, when I press the PLAY button in Unity and present the image in front of my webcam such that Vuforia can detect it, dragging one of the spheres does not deform my Cube, neither in scene nor game mode.

[This is the 3D cube with blue spheres in Scene mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SD6v.png)

Comment: We're gonna need to see the code that handles moving the points in order to help.

Comment: That's something I do not know how to implement since i'm pretty new to Unity. I did find some code online that moves my spheres, but it does not deform my 3D cube

Comment: Leap motion with AR as first project with Unity is quite of a challenge. Maybe you want to lower the challenges first. Anyway in this case you'd have to get the vertices from the mesh, find the vertex, move it, apply the new mesh to the mesh filter.